# Semantic-release release-notes-generator how to teach new types

Tags: semantic-release

Can anyone give us a hint how to configure `@semantic-release/release-notes-generator` to take extra commit types (those additional to preset ones) while generating release-notes?

Our commits-analyzer config:

```
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    {
      "preset": "angular",
      "releaseRules": [
        {
          "type": "refactor",
          "release": "patch"
        },
        {
          "type": "minfeat",
          "release": "patch"
        }
      ]
    }
```

At this moment we have no extra configuration for `@semantic-release/release-notes-generator`, and surely it requires some as new types don't show up in changelog that is generated by `@semantic-release/changelog` after release-notes-generator runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement your own [conventional-changelog preset](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog) in order to handle those new commit type.

For example the default [angular preset](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog-angular) handles only certain commit types: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/e865af4df8d06795cebc7af09364ade19119e089/packages/conventional-changelog-angular/writer-opts.js#L36